# How to prevent Dart from using my home directory?

Tags: windows, dart

I'd like to use Dart on a Windows machine where my home directory is configured to be on a network share. I have no control over this configuration.

Initially, I couldn't get the Dart Editor to run at all as the default location for its configuration folder is defined in DartEditor.ini as @user.home/DartEditor. This prevented me from creating new projects at all. I have edited this file so that my Dart Editor configuration folder is now located at c:\DartEditor which seems to solve that problem.

However, when creating a new project, Pub tries to install libraries to my home directory and Dartium tries to save its configuration there as well. This causes Pub to just fail (so I can't build any projects) and Dartium to warn me that storing it's configuration on a network share will cause it to slow down.

How can I prevent Dart Editor (and any associated tools like Pub and Dartium) from using my home directory and instead use a directory on my local drive?

Answer (score 1):

What about to download Dart and unzip it to:

```
C:\DartHome
```

I also recommend to change the DartEditor.ini file on the second line to:

```
C:\DartHome\DartEditor
```

Comment: Heya, Thanks I've tried both of those things but unfortunately, Pub and Dartium still try and use my home directory (at least)

Comment: I know, Dartium has it implemented, that it creates ".dartium" or something like this named folder. I think there must be some setting file in Dart folder (and probably in Dartium folder too), where it is all set, but I can't help you more...
Try to fill this as a bug [here](http://www.dartbug.com/)